# Scipy GMRES Iteration Taking Longer than Expected Time

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am trying to invert a dense matrix of size 50,000 + rows. I have been slowly trying to work to getting the SciPy GMRES operation to work. It seems to be taking an inordinate amount of time for one iteration. I am entering the following information:

```
x_gm = scipy.sparse.linalg.gmres(A,b,tol=1e-08,maxiter=1)
```

where A is a class object which calls a function to compute the matrix vector product A*v. This uses the Python Multiprocessing Pool command to compute the matrix vector product quickly. For the matrix I am interested in, I have timed this product A*V with a multiprocessing pool of 8 cores and it takes`about 50 seconds. However, running the above gmres command for one iteration takes 1370 seconds.I was under the impression that the bulk of the computation time would be the matrix vector product. This seems to be a bit odd and I'm wondering if there is something else going on here. Is the gmres ignoring the 1 iteration command and doing multiple iterations? Any advice or information would be appreciated.

The version of Scipy I am using is version .0.9.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maxiter` controls the number of *restart cycles*, not dot products.
The bound for dot products is `restart*maxiter`, where `restart` has the default value of 20. Indeed, `20*50 s = 1000 s`, so the time is indeed dominated by matrix-vector products.

You could have found this out yourself just by adding a print statement to your m-v product function.

Comment: Thanks, I actually was just about to edit the post since I figured it out after I tests changing the restart variable.